# Add additional element to exposed view form?

Tags: views, forms

I'm trying to modify an exposed view form by adding some additional markup.  My current code looks like this:

```
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    if ($form_state['view']->name == 'products_page') {
        // $element = array();
        $form['filter_by']['#type'] = 'item';
        $form['filter_by']['#markup'] = '<h2>Filter by:</h2>';
        $form['filter_by']['#weight'] = -10;
        // $form = array_merge($element, $form);
        $form['solution']['#options']['All'] = 'By Solution';
        $form['technology']['#options']['All'] = 'By Technology';
        $form['platform']['#options']['All'] = 'By Platform';
        $form['brand']['#options']['All'] = 'By Brand';
        $form['category']['#options']['All'] = 'By Solution';
    }

    dpm($form);
  }
```

Now I'm trying to move the `'filter_by'` element to appear first, before every other element, so I attached a weight value of -10 to it.  However, the element is being added to the container that the submit button would normally be found.

[image]

I'm completely confused...  any insight?

Answer (score 5):

Well then... apparently it's a weird lopsided solution that is necessary.  See comment #10 here http://drupal.org/node/893392.